# Why do my Java threads seem to run on one core only, when my machine has two?

Tags: java, multithreading

Why do my Java threads seem to run on one core only, when my machine has two?

My program has 10 threads and each prints more things.
In the output I can see that the printing is in such order that,
once a thread begins it finishes, and only then another thread starts printing.
So, there is none of the interleaved print statements I expected to see from different threads.

```
public class Calculator implements Runnable {

        private int number;

        public Calculator(int number) {
            this.number=number;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
                    System.out.printf("%s: %d * %d = 
                    %d\n",Thread.currentThread().getName(),number,i,i*number);
            }
        }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
                    Calculator calculator=new Calculator(i);
                    Thread thread=new Thread(calculator);
                    thread.start();
            }
    }
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: The code matters. Show us the code.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What JRE are you using?

Comment: Please add some more information (like code). I don't think you are looking at how threads work properly... Otherwise please read the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Windows 8, Eclipse Kepler, JRE version 7u51 x64.

Comment: Show us the code where you're starting up the threads. Are you invoking the `start` method, and not the `run`?

Comment: Here is the code in two files, it is very simple: http://pastebin.com/FGFu2cDr and http://pastebin.com/y2eKQNmg

Comment: Can you please edit your post and put the code there? We don't need all of it. Just where you are using the threads.

Comment: This is because each thread finishes, before the next one is started in your main loop. Try to put a delay in the threads loop.

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski Not true, the printing shows this. For example the last created thread printed second in my case.

Comment: So, the reason that your last thread printed second is because of concurrency. Your loop will finish before another thread to begin. Remember, context switching has a high cost.

Comment: Thanks guys! That was the issue.

Comment: Ya, the answer below shows that adding sleep will interweave them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shorten the discussion in the comments, and as a simple illustration, you may try this modified version of your `Calclulator`. It should print the output in a nicely mixed fashion.

```
class Calculator implements Runnable
{
    private int number;

    public Calculator(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s: %d * %d = %d\n", 
                Thread.currentThread().getName(), 
                number, i, i * number);
            someRandomDelay();
        }
    }

    private static void someRandomDelay()
    {
        int ms = (int) (100 + Math.random() * 200);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

}
```